# How to update IcedTea plugin for latest java

Tags: java, icedtea

Verifying Java Version
A newer version of Java is available

Your Java version: Version 7 Update 65
Newer Version 8 Update 25

How do I update IcedTea plugin for latest java?

Comment: Which browser do you have?

Comment: Firefox webbrowser

Answer (score 0):

If you installed using a repository, you should be able to just use

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install
```

the specific package (it will download the update if there is one in the repository). Otherwise go to the website you found the package from, then download and install it.

Comment: got it from ubuntu software centre?

Comment: See if there's an updated version there. Just fire it up and find the IcedTea plugin to check if there's an update for yours. For me, I see version 1.5-1ubuntu1 in the Software Center though, I'm guessing Ubuntu has their own versions for it maybe you have a lower version installed? I only see version 7 of IcedTea and OpenJDK in the default repositories using apt-cache search though. If I remember right, IcedTea is based off OpenJDK so you might have to wait for an update. Could be wrong there though.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like no update yet from there. Plug in in current state does currently work, just warns on some websites that java may be out of date. Let's hope icedtea gets updated soon for java 8 in the software centre.

Comment: On the website that's giving you trouble, there should be an icon in the address bar that looks like a Lego/brick, if you click it you might be able to tell the plugin to run anyway.

Comment: **Note to Chrome users; that is only for firefox users** ^^